# Ruby array repeat value if next not present,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

How can we achieve this in Ruby?

```
xs = [1,2,3]
x = 5
```

Then I need that `sum = 1+2+3+1+2 = 9`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have the abstractions you need in the core, just wire them together: [Enumerable#cycle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle), [Enumerable#take](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-take) and [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
>> [1, 2, 3].cycle.take(5).inject(0, :+)
=> 9
```

That's the [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)/declarative approach: use abstractions (either existing or those you implement yourself) so you can write code that describes *what* you are doing instead of *how* you are doing it.

Comment: very nice, about as simple as you can get.

Answer (score 3):

```
def get_sum_cyclic(array, number)
   sum = 0
   0.upto(number - 1) do |i|
     sum += array[i % array.size]
   end
   return sum
end
```

Another option is using map over a range:

```
(0...5).map{|i| a[i % a.size]}.inject(0){|t,v| t + v}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, completely forget modulus.

Comment: @izomorphius: the last snippet is pretty good, only that I'd write the more compact `.inject(0, :+)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a special way to do it in Ruby, but you can achieve this with the following snippet.

```
(0..x).inject(0) do |sum, i|
  sum += arr[ i % arr.size ]
end
```

Comment: I'd +1 this, provided you change `+=` for `+` ;-)